# Different behavior with similar code

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    vector<int> v;
};

void f0(const A&& a0)
{
    cout << &a0.v[0] << endl;
    A a1{ move(a0.v) };
    cout << &a1.v[0] << endl << endl;;
}

void f1()
{
    A a0{ vector<int>(10) };
    cout << &a0.v[0] << endl;
    A a1{ move(a0.v) };
    cout << &a1.v[0] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    f0(A{ vector<int>(10) });
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why in the first case addresses are different but in the second case addresses are same.

Comment: In f0, a0 is const, so even if it is a rvalue reference, you cannot move from it as you cannot modify it.

Comment: @galop1n That is an answer.